# Android - filled ListActivity Database Search - HowTo?

Tags: android, database, search, listactivity

I got an ListActivity which gets filled with data from the database. This activity is also allowed to search for data in the database.

```
DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
Cursor c;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    final Intent queryIntent = getIntent();
    final String queryAction = queryIntent.getAction();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(queryAction)) {
        String searchKeywords = queryIntent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        doSearch(searchKeywords);
    }
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    try {
        super.onStart();
        dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
        c = dbHelper.getAllMagazines();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c,
                new String[] {"editionName", "magazineName"},
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

        /** Adapter setzen**/
        this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

Its shows me the data from the database in the ListView. So no problem here.
When I do the search, the following function gets called:

```
private void doSearch(String search) {    
    dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
    c = dbHelper.searchEditions(getIntent().getStringExtra("search"));
    startManagingCursor(c);

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c,
            new String[] {"editionName", "magazineName"},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I set the ListAdapter to the new Adapter with the Searchresults. But in the ResultView of the Search it still shows me all data from the database I get in onStart(). If I disable the setListAdapter in onStart(), everything works fine and it shows me the searchresulst.

How can i tell the ListView to show the searchresults when the ListView is already filled with data?

FULL CODE:

```
public class MagazineViewController extends ListActivity { 

    DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
    Cursor c;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        final Intent queryIntent = getIntent();
        final String queryAction = queryIntent.getAction();
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(queryAction)) {
            String searchKeywords = queryIntent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
            doSearch(searchKeywords);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        try {
            super.onStart();
            dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);

            c = dbHelper.getAllMagazines();
            startManagingCursor(c);

            Log.d("CURSOR COUNT", ""+c.getCount());

            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c,
                    new String[] {"editionName", "magazineName"},
                    new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});

            this.setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    private void doSearch(String search) {    
        dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);

        /** Daten aus der Datenbank abfragen**/
        Cursor cur = dbHelper.searchEditions(getIntent().getStringExtra("search"));
        startManagingCursor(cur);

        Log.d("CURSOR COUNT", ""+cur.getCount());

        final ListView view = getListView();
        final SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = ((SimpleCursorAdapter) view.getAdapter());
        cursorAdapter.changeCursor(cur);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.magazinemenu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.preferences:
                startActivity (new Intent (this, PreferencesViewController.class));
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
 03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{package/package.MagazineViewController}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at package.MagazineViewController.doSearch(MagazineViewController.java:111)
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at package.MagazineViewController.onCreate(MagazineViewController.java:40)
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-30 16:29:43.381: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(546):     ... 11 more
```

Error Code in line 111, which is         cursorAdapter.changeCursor(cur);

Answer (score 1):

MagazineViewController.class:

```
public class MagazineViewController extends ListActivity { 

DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = null;
Cursor c;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    final Intent queryIntent = getIntent();
    final String queryAction = queryIntent.getAction();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(queryAction)) {
        String searchKeywords = queryIntent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
        doSearch(searchKeywords);
    }

    dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);

    c = dbHelper.getAllMagazines();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    Log.d("CURSOR COUNT", ""+c.getCount());

    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c,
                new String[] {"editionName", "magazineName"},
                new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});


    this.setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private void doSearch(String search) {    
    dbHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);

    Cursor cur = dbHelper.searchEditions(search);
    startManagingCursor(cur);

    Log.d("CURSOR2 COUNT", ""+cur.getCount());

    adapter.changeCursor(cur);
}
```

DatabaseHelper.class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "magazineDB";
public static final String TABLE_MAGAZINE = "magazine";
public static final String TABLE_EDITION = "edition";
public static final String TABLE_ARTICLE = "article";
public static final String TABLE_KEYWORDS = "keywords";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,1);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MAGAZINE + " (magazineId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
"magazineName TEXT);");

    /** Tabelle "Edition" erstellen **/
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EDITION + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
"editionId INTEGER, " +
"editionName TEXT, " +
"editionContent TEXT, " +
"magazine_id INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
"FOREIGN KEY (magazine_id) REFERENCES " + TABLE_MAGAZINE + "(magazineId));");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER fki_edition_magazine_id " +
            " BEFORE INSERT ON "+ TABLE_EDITION +
            " FOR EACH ROW BEGIN"+
            " SELECT CASE WHEN ((SELECT magazineId FROM "+ TABLE_MAGAZINE +" WHERE magazineId = new.magazine_id ) IS NULL)"+
            " THEN RAISE (ABORT,'Foreign Key Violation') END;"+
            "  END;");

}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_MAGAZINE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_EDITION);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_ARTICLE);

    db.execSQL("DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS fki_edition_magazine_id");

    onCreate(db);
}

Cursor getAllMagazines() {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cur= db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM edition, magazine WHERE edition.magazine_id = magazine.magazineId", null);
    return cur; 
}

public Cursor searchEditions (String searchtext) {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cur= db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM edition, magazine WHERE edition.magazine_id = magazine.magazineId AND edition.editionContent LIKE '%" + searchtext + "%'" ,null);

    return cur;
}
```

Comment: Finally I got the solution! I have to initial the ListAdapter before the doSearch() in the onCreate() Method. Thank you elevine for your help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling SimpleCursorAdapter.[changeCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#changeCursor%28android.database.Cursor%29) on your existing adapter instead of creating a new adapter instance.

I don't think you need these lines:

```
final ListView view = getListView();
final SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = ((SimpleCursorAdapter) view.getAdapter());
```

Chage:

```
cursorAdapter.changeCursor(cur);
```

To:

```
adapter.changeCursor(cur);
```

Comment: if i change to adapter.changeCursor(c); instead of creating a new adapter instance, i get a NullPointerException. But cursor count > 0.

Comment: Is the exception telling you that the adapter is null?  Can you provide your new code and full stack trace?  Can you show us all of the code in your Activity?

Comment: i already tried that before. But also get the NullPointerException. And i dont know why :-/

Comment: another error i got was: Cursor cur = dbHelper.searchEditions(getIntent().getStringExtra("search"));
it should be Cursor cur = dbHelper.searchEditions(search); still get the NullPointerException but cursor count > 0

Comment: The Exception you posted was a RuntimeException, not NullPointerException, so what is the stack trace for the NullPointerException?

Comment: The code I suggested you remove is redundant.  You already have a variable in your class for the adapter, why are trying to get it again?  Also, it would help to see the code for your DatabaseHelper class. I don't understand why you are creating a new instance of it so often.

Comment: i postet the 2 classes in another answer.